# XSD. How to make restriction to capitalize the first letter of a word

Tags: xml, xsd, restriction

I am trying to restrict my xml to forbid a certain word because the first letter is not capital ?
For example,a name field. A name cannot start with a small letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `xs:pattern` facet with a value such as `\p{Lu}.*`.

If this is for personal names, do be aware that there are people named "ffinch" who will get very upset if you capitalise their names incorrectly.